# problem with tabbed interface as mentioned in the article of josh smith

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a problem with my program.

Here is the link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2734432/TabbedInterface.7z

Once you have opened both tabs, you'll start losing the references to other collections of the current item in the view. That is because these IDs are nullable and once you switch over to the other tab they'll become null. My question is: why and how can I correct that behavior?

If you change the `int?` to `int` there are no more problems, but I need them to be nullable!

Comment: A word of advice: Not many people here will take the time to download your program and try to get it up and running in their environments. Post the code that's failing, or if it's too big, post a short snippet of where you think the problem is and put the full source code file on pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tabbed interface in the article is half baked, its has other problems as:

- It opens two tabs for the same record
- The list get changed even when the changes are not commited by the user
- You can't doble-click the list to go the record
- etc.

Check other frameworks as Prism for more ready-to-use solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com). It contains the Writer sample application which comes with an **improved tabbed interface**.